# Load all hierarchical references with Servicestack ORMLite

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

Is there any way to preload all nested and sub-nested references with servicestack / ormlite?

```
 public class Person

{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Pants))]
    public int PantsId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Pants Pants { get; set; }

}

public class Pants
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Pocket))]
    public int PocketId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Pocket Pocket { get; set; }

}

public class Pocket
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Depth { get; set; }

}

Db.LoadSelect<Person>()
```

When I load a person using Db.LoadSelect()  it only fetches references up to person.Pants... person.Pants.Pocket is null.  I would have to do a Db.LoadReferences(person.Pants) for it to load the pocket reference.

Any way of automatically loading all the nested references, or is it limited to one layer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrmLite's `db.Load*` API's is limited to loading 1-level depth of references. The `Db.LoadReferences(instance)` can be used to further fetch the disconnected POCO's references.

You should also be mindful if loading references individually to avoid **N+1** queries by loading them in a loop, i.e. when possible it's better to use a single query to fetch related records to avoid multiple db hits.

Comment: What is the reason for the 1-level limitation? Is it to avoid possibly generating more queries than the developer might think it would? And which should anyway be called with a single Select and "stitched together" yourself (i.e. connect object pointers once loaded)?

Comment: @specimen OrmLite APIs returns clean populated disconnected POCOs, i.e. it doesn't use proxy classes to be able to trigger lazy N+1 queries on object navigation.